# Should my small non-proft allow users to forward email from our Google Apps account to their personal Gmail?

Tags: gmail, google, application

I am a user of multiple gmail accounts and have no problem with using multiple sign-in for my mail access. But we have a new employee that would rather all his email in one inbox. I know he *can* forward the mail to his personal account, and that a bcc could put a copy of any replies back into his work account, but I feel like I should have some privacy concerns with this.  Any input would be great!

Comment: No, a thousand times no.

Comment: It isn't a sysadmin issue.  It is a legal issue, and a branding issue.  If he forwards his mail to his personal account, then what when he replies.  The messages will appear to come from his personal account then from the non-profit.  Also remind him that he would making it likely for his personal email to be subpoenaed.  Depending on the type of org you may have FOIA laws that apply to you meaning an random person can basically request every bit of information.  If applicable messages are being sent from his account, then you must search his account, and he must permit it.

Comment: @Zoredache Re: branding, you can set up your personal Gmail to send as your work address for any e-mail with that in the To header. It's quite easy.

Comment: @ceejayoz, yes, but that can't be forced by the organization on a personal account..  If the person decides to start stealing customers, he can simply choose to not set that, or remove it at some later point in time.

Comment: @Zoredache I'm just pointing out that it's possible to address that particular concern. In a small organization of a couple people, it'd be fairly easy to enforce.

Answer (score 2):

No! Heck no!

Whatever happens if you ever get into an argument with this person?

- Would he then be allowed to keep the only copy of all work related mails in his personal account and leave?
- Would his personally account suddenly belong to the non-profit? (And registered as such so that **you** can prove it is **your account** and that you can delete if afterward (incl. all old private mails).